# re.capture multiple groups matching the same pattern python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to capture the contents between timestamps from a dataframe column.

The data present in the dataframe column consists of timestamp followed by text then single or multiple new line characters followed by text and so forth.

My objective is the capture all the text within the column separated by timestamps.

I have been able to capture the first group of text by the below pattern search but want to repeat the same or a better way to capture the entire text in column.

My objective is to capture the highlighted text in the image attached.

I have used the below pattern search and been able to capture the first group matching.

```
pattern=re.compile(r'(^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})(\s[-].*\n)(\D*[.])')
```

Output: Job transactions done successfully through application transactions.

The text to search over is

> 1997-09-01 12:30:14 - ABCD (Additional comments) Job transactions done
>   successfully through application transactions. 1997-09-01 11:46:22 -
>   EFGH (Additional comments) Case set. Team to follow up with Support
>   for resolution. 1997-09-01 09:15:00 - ABC (Additional comments)
>   Acknowledged. This does not impact application functionality. It was a
>   one off job executed . We will need to discuss this with Team and
>   check the logs to investigate the issue. This should be changed to
>   'low' severity because the job can be re-run at any time of the day.

Comment: please don't post text data as images. It's unreasonable to expect people to copy things out of an image for testing purposes.

Comment: Apologies. Text:

1997-09-01 12:30:14 - ABCD (Additional comments)
Job transactions done successfully through application transactions.

1997-09-01 11:46:22 - EFGH (Additional comments)
Case set.  Team to follow up with Support for resolution.

1997-09-01 09:15:00 - ABC (Additional comments)
Acknowledged.



This does not impact application functionality.



It was a one off job executed .

We will need to discuss this with Team and check the logs to investigate the issue.



This should be changed to 'low' severity because the job can be re-run at any time of the day.

Comment: Don't post vital info in comments either. Edit the question and replace the image. It shouldn't be there at all.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is possible to do this using a capture group, I would find it easier to do something like this:

```
import re

sample="""1997-09-01 12:30:14 - ABCD
Job transactions done successfully through application transactions

1997-90-01 09:15:00 - ABC
Acknowledged

This does not impact functionality.
"""

def date_match(s):
    """Returns true if the beginning of this string matches a date and time."""
    return bool(re.match("\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}", s))

def yeild_matches(full_log):
    log = [] # keep track of this log
    for line in full_log.split("\n"): # for each line
        if date_match(line): # if this line starts with a date
            if len(log) > 0: # if theres already a log...
                # remove the first line (which included the date), and include this line of the log if its not an empty line
                lines = [l for l in log[1:] if l.strip()]
                yield "\n".join(lines) # yield the log
                log = [] # ... and set the log back to nothing.

        log.append(line) # add the current line to log (list)

    yield "\n".join([l for l in log[1:] if l.strip()]) # return the last log (theres no date at the end of the logs to end the last log)

logs = list(yeild_matches(sample))

for i, l in enumerate(logs, 1):
    print("Match {}:\n{}".format(i, l))
```

Output:

```
Match 1:
Job transactions done successfully through application transactions
Match 2:
Ackownledged
This does not impact functionality.
```

Comment: Thanks Sean. Just a query is it possible to apply the same logic on a dataframe column containing the same format of data as in the sample above and convert it on the a string of sentences.

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with `pandas` myself. (I think thats what you're referring to)

Comment: Yes.No issues.Thanks for the suggestion. Will check for any additional responses.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [positive lookbehind and a positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check for the timestamp format:

`[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}`

**Note** that the format does not make it a valid date and or time.

[`(?<=[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} - ).*?(?=[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} - |$)`](https://regex101.com/r/cjol8H/1)

Another option in python could be to split on the timestamp format:

```
import re
s = """1997-09-01 12:30:14 - ABCD (Additional comments) Job transactions done successfully through application transactions. 1997-09-01 11:46:22 - EFGH (Additional comments) Case set. Team to follow up with Support for resolution. 1997-09-01 09:15:00 - ABC (Additional comments) Acknowledged. This does not impact application functionality. It was a one off job executed . We will need to discuss this with Team and check the logs to investigate the issue. This should be changed to 'low' severity because the job can be re-run at any time of the day."""

print(filter(None, re.split(r'[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} - ', s)))
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/RMIH31707)